# jpenable crashes while attaching JProfiler to JVM in offline mode

Tags: jprofiler

I use jprofiler 7.2.2, app server (JBoss) is running java 1.6.0_30. The same user is used to start JBoss and JProfiler.

I execute jpenable,  choose offline mode, provide my setting file and then process fails with two different errors:

```
    Using the single session in the config file.
ERROR: Attaching is not supported: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:100)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:195)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.b(ejt:266)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:253)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:223)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.b(ejt:157)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.g(ejt:83)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.main(ejt:237)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
    Using the single session in the config file.
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
        at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.readInt(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:226)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.execute(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:193)
        at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:40)
        at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentPath(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:70)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.AgentLoader.a(ejt:26)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.b(ejt:266)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:253)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:223)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.b(ejt:157)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.g(ejt:83)
        at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.main(ejt:237)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is the profile process running as a different user than jpenable?

Comment: same user for both processes

Comment: I know this does not sound satisfactory, but sometimes the attach API in the JRE does not work for reasons that are unclear to us.